# header location is not working PHP

Tags: php, header, location

My header location is not working while also using `ob_start();`

When I am trying to login, after inserting current data it goes to some other page, now the error is we insert correct thing every thing happen correctly but it does not go to next page

Insertion is happening but Header location is not working

```
ob_start();
$insert=$db->fireQuery("insert into saveresu (`id`,`employee_id`,`date`,`email`,`emp_id`) values('','$wed','$date','$email','$emp_id')");
 if($insert) {
  header("location:profile.php");
  }
```

Comment: Please add some code to your question.

Comment: where is the code bro ?

Comment: Hi, Please see the code

Comment: any error message or behaviour worth mentioning?

Answer (score 0):

Try This, but first check weather it comes inside this if?

```
if($insert) { 
header("location:profile.php");
die; 
}
```